# Is there alternative to use outline:"none" property in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, monorepo, react-native-web

Actually, i have passed style {{ width: "100%", outline: "none", height: 50 }} to the child component, to which i am getting a warning in the terminal that outline is not valid property.
If this style declared in the stylesheet, the app crashed with an error, therefore it has to be declared inline.
I could not found a way to remove the warning, since react native don't support outline : "none" property, is there any other alternative to this.

Comment: Please reconsider removing the outline? Or at least replace it with a border which appears on hover and focus.

Comment: actually i have created a textfield with icon and TextInput flexDirection: "row", so when i click on icon the textfield is focused, now since i am using monorepo architecture so i am using react native web, in web part when textfield is focused, it adds an outline to the textfield, which looks odd, that is why i have used outline:"none", which works and removes outline in web part but gives error in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Platform API](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/platform/) from react native web to only add the `outline` style when your app is running on web.

Something like:

```
StyleSheet.create({
  textEditStyle: {
    Platform.select({
      web: {
        outline: 'none'
      }
    }),
    ... // Other styles go here
  }
});
```